# How to keep buttons close to each other (horizontally) in Qt widget?

Tags: qt, widget, qpushbutton

```
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout ();
    centralWidget->setLayout (layout);
    layout->addWidget (refresh, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget (zoomIn, 1, 0);
    layout->addWidget (zoomOut, 1, 1);
    layout->addWidget (panLeft, 2, 0);
    layout->addWidget (panRight, 2, 1);
    layout->addWidget (panTop, 3, 0);
    layout->addWidget (panBottom, 3, 1);
    layout->addWidget (findInfo, 4, 0);
    layout->addWidget (textEdit, 5, 0);

    window->setCentralWidget (centralWidget);
```

[image]

Comment: See my answer below - can you add some more context to your code? What  are the actual widget types you are using for the buttons? Did you add any constraints to the widgets? Can you post a mockup of how the UI should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need some more context. I took your code and wrapped it into the following complete sample application:

```
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    QMainWindow win;

    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(&win);
    QPushButton* refresh = new QPushButton("Start R");
    QPushButton* zoomIn = new QPushButton("Zoom in");
    QPushButton* zoomOut = new QPushButton("Zoom out");
    QPushButton* panLeft = new QPushButton("Left");
    QPushButton* panRight = new QPushButton("Right");
    QPushButton* panTop = new QPushButton("Top");
    QPushButton* panBottom = new QPushButton("Bottom");
    QPushButton* findInfo = new QPushButton("Find Info");
    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit("Vehicle Info. Will be shown here.");

///////////////////////////// Your Code
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout ();
    centralWidget->setLayout (layout);
    layout->addWidget (refresh, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget (zoomIn, 1, 0);
    layout->addWidget (zoomOut, 1, 1);
    layout->addWidget (panLeft, 2, 0);
    layout->addWidget (panRight, 2, 1);
    layout->addWidget (panTop, 3, 0);
    layout->addWidget (panBottom, 3, 1);
    layout->addWidget (findInfo, 4, 0);
    layout->addWidget (textEdit, 5, 0);

    window->setCentralWidget (centralWidget);
///////////////////////////// End your code

    win.show();
    app.connect( &app, SIGNAL( lastWindowClosed() ), &app, SLOT( quit() ) );
    return app.exec();
}
```

This results in the following layout:

[image: Screenshot]

**It looks like you have added some size constraints on the buttons, since they all have the same size in your screenshot (besides the Start button).**